# How to stream Audio from Helix Server?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, helix-server

How does Helix Server work with android application? In android developers site i found that we can assign the url to MediaPlayer to stream the audio/video. But there is no specification about buffer size.. do i need to do any more coding on server side or in android application to get the streaming work for a specific buffer rate?

I am new to streaming.. Please enlighten me regarding this.. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Helix but since both Helix and Android has support for 3gpp PSS6 you shouldn't have to manage any buffering.

And you might want to take a look at http://www.realnetworks.com/uploadedFiles/products-services/Whitepaper-Enhanced-Rate-Control.pdf for further improving the video quality when streaming to mobile devices.